# OSGi Equinox standalone application, how to

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I have been developing an osgi application for some time in eclipse using bnd. In the IDE everything works fine and so on...
now I have to export my app into an standalone osgi installation, and I just can't figure out how. This may sound confusing and I looked at some tutorials but they are way too old in most cases.

The runtime I'm using is Equinox, which depends on Apache Felix these days. Sadly the Equinox documentation is for version 3.2 I'm using 3.10

Console output trying to start osgi:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar -consoleLog
!SESSION 2015-04-23 18:17:22.987 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_79
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-04-23 18:17:23.743
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service.         Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:208)
```

Does anyone know a tutorial out there that is still up to date or simply can tell me how to configure this?

**UPDATE**

I got it working now, in case anyone has the same trouble getting started that's how it worked for me:

config.ini:

```
osgi.bundles=org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.10.0.jar@1:start,\
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar@2:start,\
org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.10.0.jar@2:start,\
org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar@2:start
osgi.noShutdown=true
eclipse.ignoreApp=true
```

shell command:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar -consoleLog -clean -console
```

filesystem:

./

```
org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.10.0.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.10.0.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar

./configuration/

config.ini
```

output:

osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."

```
id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633
1       ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
2       ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
3       ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
4       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.0.v20140131-1639
```

osgi>

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "export my app into an standalone osgi installation"? Do you want to install your bundles into a separate OSGi container or do want to create a complete application?
If the latter, how do you define your standalone application? Do you use a Eclipse product file?

Comment: no just launching the jar from shell, but I actually got it working now and will post the solution here.